# 404 Hijacking

Tags: error-handling, http-headers, http-status-code-404

Certain [malware such as AVG](http://www.avg.com/special-toolbar-404-dns-error-tlbrc.tpl-mcr1) hijack 404 pages in order to display a page in the browser riddled with their own ads.
The only work around I've found is to abandon 404 http status codes for custom error pages in my webapp.

Is there any other work around?

Edit:

Anybody know of any other toolbars/programs that also hijack 404 pages without checking whether they are generic error pages or not?

Is there a way to detect the presence of AVG from the query string or otherwise? (I assume not)

I've created a [petition to AVG](http://www.petitiononline.com/avg404/petition.html) on this.

Comment: AVG? Malware? That's an odd definition.

Comment: Actually, I see where he's coming from. It might not be hostile, but it is annoying and intrusive. So it meets 2/3 criteria, IMO. That led me to uninstall AVG.

Comment: I use AVG and chose NOT to install the toolbar.

Comment: i never install the optional toolbars.. and I rarely use browsers that respond to them (such as IE), so I've never seen this personally. I still wouldn't classify AVG as malware, though.. annoyware perhaps :)

Comment: From reading wikipedia, I believe the term grayware (or greyware, depending on your spelling) might be more applicable than malware.

Comment: Such "malware" could also be Chrome, as it too displays his own 404 instead of the server one. I hate this kind of things. I uninstalled just because of this. Anyway I too switch from avg to avira as it seems more light and doesn't have this kind of problems.

Comment: I would classify it as hostile and make a distinction between it and Chrome (and IE) as the latter only replace the generic 404 pages.  My error page is custom and site specific.

Answer (score 16):

It’s not your fault and it’s certainly not your responsibility. Keep the HTTP status codes, they are useful. If some of your users decide to install a browser plugin which handles 404 status codes, don't try to work around it.

[There is a Google Webmaster Central Blog post about this topic](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/08/farewell-to-soft-404s.html):

> [...] are
>   confusing for users, and furthermore
>   search engines may spend much of their
>   time crawling and indexing
>   non-existent, often duplicative URLs
>   on your site. This can negatively
>   impact your site's crawl
>   coverage - because of the time Googlebot
>   spends on non-existent pages, your
>   unique URLs may not be discovered as
>   quickly or visited as frequently.

Comment: Hmmm, I'd like to accept your answer and 'do the right thing', but the user in question had no idea that installing an anti-virus package would affect the browser, and clearly believed it was a problem with my site.

Comment: You could place a note on your 404 error page, which explains this issue.

Comment: I wouldn't be too worried about search-engine-bots & crawl-coverage as I assume sitemap.xml takes care of that.  I take this proclamation from google as benign scaremongering to promote good web practices.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the protection racket that is Antivirus software highjacks 404 pages. That's not a reason to abandon the status code, though. Let the user suffer until he learns.

Some software, such as google's chrome only highjack the 404 pages if they are under a certain size, so make sure to create a somewhat meaning- and helpful error page.

Comment: I believe I read that Chrome actually looks for the generic ones issued by servers (IIS, Apache, etc) that are among the more technical and only change those to more consumer friendly errors. I'm not sure that it's just size, though.

Comment: "Let the user suffer until he learns." is not acceptable from a usability perspective, and certainly sounds inhumane.  While I agree with the sentiment, it does not solve the problem of displaying the page correctly to all users, no matter how naive.

Answer (score 2):

When you describe AVG as "malware" are you refering to the antivirus software?

I do not think malware means what you think it means.

Aside from abandoning the 404 code I doubt there is much you can do, as the client is free to do whatever it wan't with your 404.

I had a firefox plugin that checked the internet archive for an archived version of any 404 page I encountered.

If its not 404 then don't tell me it's 404 and I wont treat it like it's a 404...

Comment: Yes, I understand what malware means, and believe that it applies to a program (AVG) that injects it's own ads into another program (your browser), with little (if any) attribution as to the origin of the page.

Comment: I'm not an AVG user, so I've never seen it.  However, any software that hijacks the return codes is malware in my book.

Comment: @Brian, I think Omar's example shows your statement to be clearly untrue (Although, I suppose it *handles* rather than *hijacks* the 404 ;-).